# How to add default extensions with the Notepad++ Run... feature?

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

I regularly use notepad++ for editing my AutoHotkey scripts. I like to use the notepad++>Run feature to test them and validate them.

It works good but here's what would take it to the next level -- When I go Run > Run... > ... (to select file) > It opens the file picker window and by default it looks for exe's, .com, .cmd, .bat, etc. How can I also have it look for .ahk extensions? It's quite ridiculous to always have to select "all files." I would be extremely surprised if this isn't a hidden feature somewheres...

[image: file picker example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

*Please forgive me if I go over anything you are already aware of in this answer.*

---

> How can I also have it look for `.ahk` extensions?

Offhand, I am not aware of a way to affect the file picker dialog in Notepad++ to add default executable extensions.

> I regularly use Notepad++ for editing my AutoHotkey scripts. I like to use the Notepad++ *Run* feature to test them and validate them.

Assuming that:

- You aren't selecting files other than the ones you are currently working on in Notepad++ (i.e. the ones you have open).
- The files you are working on have an `.ahk` extension and have been saved at least once.
- You have registered the `.ahk` extension with AutoHotkey in Windows.

There should be no need modify the file picker dialog. Notepad++ has the ability to save *Run...* commands, including some very generic ones.

In particular, Notepad++ has a variable called `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` which is populated either once a file is saved or if a file is opened from a previously saved file. You can use this variable in conjunction with the *Run...* command to run the current file, including `.ahk` scripts (which should, again, be possible if the `.ahk` extension is registered with AutoHotkey in Windows).

**Running AutoHotkey Scripts In Notepad++**

1. Open *Run* → *Run...* in Notepad++ (<kbd>F5</kbd>).
2. In the *Run...* dialog box, type `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and then click `Save`. Note that the double-quotes are to ensure that paths with spaces work correctly.

*ex. Saving A Run... Command (Save)*

[image: Notepad++ Run... Dialog - Save - Screenshot]

3. A new dialog will open where you can give the saved command a name (required) and keyboard shortcut (optional). Click `OK` once you are done.

*ex. Saving A Run... Command (Options)*

[image: Notepad++ Run... Dialog - Save Options - Screenshot]

4. You will be returned to the *Run...* dialog, which you can safely `Cancel` out of assuming you don't wish to run the current file at that moment.

*ex. Saving A Run... Command (Finish)*

[image: Notepad++ Run... Dialog - Cancel - Screenshot]

5. You should now have a new option under *Run* which will allow you to run the current file open in Notepad++ (including `.ahk` files, with the caveats already noted.)

*ex. Saved Run... Command*

[image: Notepad++ - Saved Run... Command - Screenshot]

To be clear, functioning `.ahk` scripts should simply run in the Windows notification area as usual and non-functioning scripts should display the normal AutoHotkey error dialog detailing any issues encountered.